"Padded and trussed"?

Padded and trussed, his face smeared with Vaseline, a rubber
mouthpiece between his teeth, he stood waiting while two squat men
punched and grappled in the ring.

It is an excerpt from the novel Fat City by Leonard Gardner.
I can't understand to what these words refer. I guess the "padded" implies that his gloves or his head-guard is stuffed with cotton wool, and the word "trussed" implies that they wrap his hands for boxing.
Is this correct assumption?
Thank you for your time.

I expect your guess is correct. But the usage sounded odd to me, so  I asked chatgt do we say a boxer is "padded" when he's got his boxing gloves on? To which it replied No, we don’t typically say a boxer is "padded" when wearing boxing gloves. Instead, we might say the boxer is "gloved up" or simply "wearing gloves." The term "padded" is usually used to describe something with protective padding but isn’t commonly used to refer to a boxer putting on gloves." It's not really important anyway. He's fully kitted and greased up ready for his turn in the ring, no? All else is irrelevant detail

This isn't a standard phrase, I think it's something Gardner made up.

Are they sparring on having an actual boxing match?

@TimR they are sparring.

Boxers often wear padded head gear, groin protection, and other padding when sparring.  The groin protection could be called a truss

@TimR in the preceding sentences he referred to it (leather cup) if by saying this word "truss", he meant groin protection, isn't that redundancy? . " Looking at those high white shoes, Ernie pushed his hands into heavy gloves held braced for him by the wrists. He stepped into a leather foulproof cup. A head-guard was jerked over his brows."

@SoroushGh I think the author is just using different words to describe the same thing  (a cup and a truss) so as not to repeat himself. It's a fairly common thing for writers to do.

I don't have the paragraph before me to give an opinion on it, but when novelists restate, or offer a succinct summary of a situation described earlier, we don't typically accuse them of redundancy.

@PeterJennings can we say, he made up this word "trussed" to avoid saying this sentence again "He stepped into a leather foulproof cup." and also he made up this word "padded " to avoid saying " he wore gloves and headgear".

The boxers were sparring, and hence they had their usual protection on.
I don't think "padded" refers to stuffing gloves or
head-guard with cotton wool.   These are professional pieces ready for use anytime.
We can use padded to mean
the boxers wore their protective headgear.
Separately, they gloved up.
For trussed, sense 1 meaning applies:

verb
To truss someone means to tie them up very tightly so that they cannot move.

Here the coach taped up the boxers' fists tightly before helping them wear their gloves.
truss
